# Error in model.frame.default(formula ...)

Tags: r

I'm trying to make an R script to allow users to input a dataset and then display the predictive rate parity graph for their corresponding dataset. I have most of the code but when I attempt to test it with a dataset, I receive an error.

The code is below:

```
library(mltools)
library(fairness)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

calculate_fairness_metric <- function(newdata, target, sensitive_attr, base) {
  
  set.seed(77)
  val_percent <- 0.2
  val_idx     <- sample(1:nrow(new_data))[1:round(nrow(new_data) * val_percent)]
  df_train <- new_data[-val_idx, ]
  df_valid <- new_data[ val_idx, ]
  
  model1 <- glm(target ~ ., 
                data   = df_train, 
                family = binomial(link = 'logit'))
  
  
  df_valid$prob_1 <- predict(model1, df_valid, type = 'response')
  
  res1 <- pred_rate_parity(data         = df_valid, 
                           outcome      = target, 
                           outcome_base = '0', 
                           group        = sensitive_attr,
                           probs        = 'prob_1', 
                           cutoff       = 0.5, 
                           base         = base)
  
  return(res1$Metric)
}

calculate_fairness_metric(revised, "readmitted", "race", "Caucasian")
```

**Error in model.frame.default(formula = target ~ ., data = df_train, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) :
variable lengths differ (found for 'race')**

The dataset I used is below:
[dataset image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IQpE.png)

Comment: You can't use a variable `target` equal to the string `"race"` inside a formula. I often use `as.formula(paste(target, "~ ."))` in cases like this.

Comment: I added that and now I'm getting a new error which says **Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels**. All of the factors have 2 or more levels so I am not sure why that's happening

Comment: Maybe in your randomly sampled training data some of the factors don't have two levels. Can't really do much but guess without sample data illustrating the problem....